# Does the experimental QGIS2leaf plugin not work on mac OS?

Tags: qgis, leaflet, mac

I am trying to get the experimental QGIS2leaf (Leaflet web maps) plugin to work on my macbook air (2012, Mavericks OS), but when I open the outputted index.html file, no interactive image shows up in my web browser (I have tried Chrome, Safari, and Firefox).

Is this a common issue with the QGIS2leaf plugin? Is there a work around?

Comment: developer reporting in. Please explain what type of data you are extracting with the plugin and whether you're using the experimental version from the plugin repo or the one from github?

Comment: Furthermore it would be good to see the error (console/firebug) and the index.html. Why are you relying on the experimental?

Comment: This is the error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vinnyricciardi/.qgis2/python/plugins/qgis2leaf/qgis2leafdialog.py", line 119, in export2leaf
    qgis2leaf_exec(self.outFileName, self.basemapName, self.width, self.height, self.extent, self.full_screen, self.layer_list, self.visible, self.opacity, self.encode2JSON,self.createcluster)
  File "/Users/vinnyricciardi/.qgis2/python/plugins/qgis2leaf/qgis2leaf_exec.py", line 173, in qgis2leaf_exec
    if i.rendererV2().dump()[0:6] == 'SINGLE' and i.geometryType() == 0:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dump'

Comment: I was trying to export point and polygon layers. Am I going about this very wrong? It most likely is a user issue - I'm new here!

Comment: which qgis version do you use?!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that info. I am using the 0.96 version available through the QGIS plugin directory.

Answer (score 2):

We face an issue when you have xls/xlsx files in your layer list. A friend of mine found this bug.
If you're using the xls to show some points, export the resulting points as a shapefile and add it back to your qgis project. remove the xls document from your layer list. It also works when you uncheck your csv/xls whatever table layer you have, so this will not be exported.

this fails:
[image: two layers one is a xlsx file, both selected in qgis2leaf for export]

this works:
[image: two layers one is a xlsx file, only one is selected in qgis2leaf for export (the shapefile, not the table]
please recheck as I've uploaded the latest version of qgis2leaf to the qgis plugin repo:

http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis2leaf/version/0.96/

If there are still issues, please open an issue here: https://github.com/Geolicious/qgis2leaf/issues